# How can I increase the rotational speed of a stepper motor by creating an assembly program on a PIC16f84a?

Tags: stepper-motor

For the hardware I am using a 10MHz Xtal Oscillator, two 22pf, and Step Motor 28BYJ-48 5V DC

Below is the code that I have done so far. How can I increase the rotational speed of the step motor? I tried putting a low value (0Ah) to COUNT1 however, it did not rotate instead it only caused the step motor to vibrate. Please help me solve this tiny problem of mine.

```
; CONFIG
; __config 0xFFF1
 __CONFIG _FOSC_XT & _WDTE_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _CP_OFF

RES_VECT  CODE    0x0000        ; processor reset vector
    GOTO    BEGIN           ; go to beginning of program

;Constants
    
STATUS  EQU 03h
TRISB   EQU 86h
PORTB   EQU 06h
COUNT1  EQU 08h
 

MAIN_PROG CODE              ; let linker place main program

BEGIN   
bsf STATUS,5        ; go to bank 1
    movlw   00h             ; put 0000 to w register
    movwf   TRISB           ; make all pins as output
    bcf STATUS,5            ; goto bank 0
    
PROCESS 
    movlw   b'10000000'
    movwf   PORTB      
    CALL    DELAY
    
    movlw   b'01000000'
    movwf   PORTB
    CALL    DELAY
    
    movlw   b'00100000'
    movwf   PORTB
    CALL    DELAY
    
    movlw   b'00010000'
    movwf   PORTB
    CALL    DELAY
    
GOTO    PROCESS             ; loop forever

DELAY   
 LOOP   
    DECFSZ COUNT1,1         ; subtract 1 to the total COUNT1 value  
    GOTO LOOP              ; until reaches zero
   RETURN                  ; return to PROCESS
    
END
```

Comment: Try the [EE.SE forum](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) for this question. Be sure to fully describe your hardware. Also be aware that steppers torque falls with speed, and typically becomes a serious issue around 1000Hz step rate (300RPM with standard 200 step/rev motor). So squeezing the last drop out of your 10MHz micro with assembly code generally won't make the motor faster. (in some cases you may be able to refine control, IMO not worth it unless you're already an assembly wiz )

Comment: Any reason that the code is developed using Assembly, why not a higher level language like 'C'